# Is it necessary for a Drone to have a battery with the same Voltage and Amperes as the motors?

Tags: motor

Is it necessary for a Drone to have a battery with the **same Voltage and Amperes** as the motors?

Comment: Only the voltage. Amperes have to be same or higher.

Comment: Why only Voltage and not Amperes?

Comment: There are motor drivers that regulate the current to each motor to control speed.

Comment: If the amperes of the batery are higher don't you break the motors?

Comment: @MichaelSzer No because there are motor drivers that regulate the current to each motor to control speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drone (Quadracopters and the like) motors have a wide range of operating voltage support. For example many devices use from 2S (8.6 V) through 8s (34.4 V) for any given motor.
The current drawn by the motor will depend on the lifting load, speed (controlled by the prop specification) and efficiency (typically 80-90%). The lifting power is very approximately the operating voltage times the current times efficiency (typically fractional horsepower or Watts).

The motors only draw the current required as set by the speed controller, so the potential current capacity of the batteries can be much more that that required by the motors (combined) and no harm can come.
The maximum RPM of the motor is eventually limited by the maximum voltage you can apply and the current limit through the motor.

Go to any RC hobby shop and you will be able to see power curves for motors specified with particular props.

At the very minimum you will see motor specs like [this](http://www.quadrocopter.com/Tiger-U5-Motor-400KV_p_1217.html):

[image]

Comment: So what is important is that the battery has at least Volts to support the motors and doesn't matter if it has a lot more Volts than what the motors support?

Comment: Yes, it does matter if the battery has higher voltage than the motors are rated for.

Comment: "_it does matter if the battery has a higher voltage than the motors are rated for_" Yes, that there is no problem or that if they are higher it can break the motors?

Comment: If the battery voltage exceeds the motor rating it may damage the motor.  Most speed controllers don't regulate the voltage, they only modulate the voltage to regulate average current.  And generally a motor can't draw more current than it can handle assuming the voltage is not exceeded.  So as long as the controller is rated for the battery voltage and motor max current, and the motor is rated for the battery voltage, it should be OK.

Comment: Thanks buddy, post it as an answer and I will mark as the correct one.

Comment: @MichaelSzer: It does not matter if it's a bit more. But not a lot more. Motors are also rated with maximum voltage (for RC equipment typically used in drones this rating is typically specified in number of lithium cells instead of volts - for example a motor designed for 3-4S vs a motor designed for 6s). If you use a 6S battery to power a 3S motor then your motor will most likely burn after running for about 2 minutes.

Comment: @MichaelSzer: Long story short: using too little voltage for a motor (for example a 2S battery for a 4S motor) will not give you enough power to lift your drone (of if it does then you could have chosen a much lighter motor to improve performance). Using too high a voltage will overheat the motor and burn the coils (in some instances will actually cause fire)